# insertion after query for azure table storage

Tags: c#, azure

I am using the table service of Azure storage.
My program will always receive entities and then insert them to a table of Azure storage.
Before inserting an entity to the table, the program will search the table whether the entity is existed or not.
There are multiple instance, to eliminate duplication, the program need to lock the table during the query-then-insert operation. Is there any locking mechanism for Azure table storage?
I think I need to lock the table or partition during a certion query-then-insert operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the existing native Azure API [Insert or Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableoperation.insertormerge.aspx)  or [Insert or Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableoperation.insertorreplace.aspx) methods.